# P5.js : manually calculate additive blendmode with pixels[]

Tags: processing, pixel, blending

I’m currently coding a P5.js program in which I draw some random generated patterns like this :

```
function setup() {
     colorMode(RGB, 255, 255, 255, 255);
     blendMode(ADD);
}

function draw() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    {
      x = generateCoordinatesX();
      y = generateCoordinateY();

      var pointColor = generateColor(); //rgba

      stroke(pointColor);
      point(x, y);
     }
}
```

When two ore more points get supperposed, they are displayed with additive BlendMode.
As the number of point is quite big, it slows down the simulation a lot. I tried to adapt this code with the pixels method like bellow to speed up things :

```
function draw() {
    loadPixels();
    for(var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    {
      x = generateCoordinatesX();
      y = generateCoordinateY();
      var index = (x + y * width)*4;
      
      pixels[index+0] += ???;
      pixels[index+1] += ???;
      pixels[index+2] += ???;
      pixels[index+3] += ???;
     }
     updatePixels();
}
```

The issue is that i dont know how to generate the R,G,B,A value so that it behave with additive Blending like my first version.
Is there a way to manually calculate this ? I tried with formulas i found but after some tests, the results are different.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of very helpful methods that will fill in this information for you. They are respectively named `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha`, and you can use them to extract the relevant information from a known color.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

 background(color(0, 255, 0));
}

function draw() {
}

function mouseClicked() {
  let blendColor = color(128,0,0);
  let density = pixelDensity();
  
  loadPixels();
  for (var i=0; i<width*height*density*4; i+=4)
  {
    pixels[i] += red(blendColor);
    pixels[i+1] += green(blendColor);
    pixels[i+2] += blue(blendColor);
    pixels[i+3] += alpha(blendColor);
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Once you click on the canvas, it'll update the background color by adding the `blendColor` to the pixel array. I deliberately choose a color that you can blend more than once to demonstrate that there won't be any stack overflow if you try to blend two colors which should go over 8-bit (255) in intensity, so you can click more than once without fearing a crash.

Hope it helps. Have fun!